# Android Studio Cannot Show the List of Devices Via USB

Tags: windows-10, usb, android, android-studio, adb

My android studio does not show the list of devices to run the app. But when I run 'adb devices' from the terminal, I can see my device and can install the app from here. I have tried everything but could not resolve the issue. I am on Windows 10, Android Studio 3.5.1, Phone: One plus 6T. Another thing, my current driver on Windows 10 is MTB USB Device. I tried to change it to google driver from SDK\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb, but it prompts a message that it is not compatible coz of 64 bit (image attached below). I am pretty sure it is 64 bit. I have the updated version of all SDKs as well. Have anyone gone through this, please let me know. It would be a great help. I have tried all basic the basic stuff like turning on developer options, MTP<-> PTP swap, changing USB port, etc.

[It display No Devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHtDj.jpg)

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9oBL.jpg)

[Adding Google Driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP0Cj.jpg)

Comment: did you ensure that your adb version, and the adb version of Android Studio match?

Comment: @Gizmo Thank you for your comment. I am not able to view adb version of my phone. I tried "adb version" to check version of my Desktop. It provides me a message: "Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32". To check adb version of Phone, I tried "adb shell adbd --version"

Comment: When you run the Connection Assistant (No Devices > Troubleshoot device connections) does it detect the Android USB device? The ADB tool should be located in your SDK path, then platform-tools folder, e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`, when running your command prompt there, and running `adb devices`, does it show devices? Try also installing the driver from your phone "CD" drive (in `Computer`)